# counting the total element of a dynamic array

Tags: arrays, c

I want to count the total element of a dynamic array.
I had search it on another source, and all I got just a static array.
How I can count it from a dynamic array?
Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *arr;
    int sz, input, length;

    printf("input size of array:");
    scanf("%d", &sz);

    arr = (int *)malloc(sz * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &input);
    }

    length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr)[0];
    printf("Number of elements present in given array: %d", length);

    return 0;
}
```

and the output i just get 1

```
PS D:\Materi Kuliah\1031101 DASPRO\Semester 1\Week-14\Review W6-W7> ./a
input size of array:6
1 
1
2
2
3
3
Number of elements present in given array: 1
```

Comment: That's impossible

Answer (score -1):

`arr` is a pointer type, `sizeof(arr)` is the size of a pointer on your system. To count the number of elements, you can either use the `sz` variable, or if you are using GCC, use one of the builtin functions for counting the number of elements.

Comment: well in other case, i have 2 array and the size has depends on user input.
but here i want to check the duplicate character, that the algorithm is

for (int i = 0; i < sizeChar; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < sizeChar; j++)
        {
            if (karakter[i] == karakter[j])
            {
                duplicate[i] = karakter[i];
            }
        }
    }

i want to put the duplicate character on duplicate[], and then i want to count the element inside it to check how much the duplicate character.
if i print the sizeChar, that's will be a different thing